# Is it possible to get push notifications from an one ASP.NET MVC3 form to another ASP.NET MVC3 form via windows notification hub?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, azure

I found how to send push notifications from ASP.NET MVC3 form via via windows notification hub([link](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/notification-hubs/notify-users-aspnet/?fb=ru-ru)). But how I can get this notifications in another ASP.NET MVC3 site?

Comment: please clarify the term "form", afaik "form" is from "webforms" and is not used inside MVC, did you mean website/controller/view

Answer (score 0):

Your second site would need to subscribe to receive the notification from the hub.  See: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/notification-hubs/notify-users-aspnet/